# subtract mean from every element dplyr

Tags: r, scale, dplyr

I want to demean all my columns using dplyr. I tried but failed using the "do()" command.

I basically want to replicate the following using easier dplyr commands:

```
tickers <- c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10))
df <- data.frame(cbind(tickers,rep(1:20),rep(2:21)))
colnames(df) <- c("tickers","col1","col2")
df %>%  group_by(tickers)
apply(df[,2:3],2,function(x) x - mean(x))
```

I am sure this can be done much better using dplyr.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `colMeans` `df[2:3]-colMeans(df[2:3])[col(df[2:3])]`

Comment: How would I do so using dplyr though? specifically if I have many columns which I want to demean using ideally a do command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we are using `dplyr`, we can do this with `mutate_each` and use any of the methods mentioned in `?select` to match the columns.  Here, I am using `matches` which can take regular expression as pattern.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate_each(funs(.-mean(.)), matches('^col')) %>%
    select(-tickers)
```

But this can be done also using `base R`:

```
df[2:3]-colMeans(df[2:3])[col(df[2:3])]
```

The `colMeans` output is a `vector` which can be replicated so that the lengths will be the same.

Comment: That looks awesome yes, but it says on mine "matches" function not found?

Comment: @Nick I am using `dplyr_0.4.3.9000`.  Which version do you have?

Comment: @Nick check if you have `starts_with('col')`

Comment: I am using dplyr_0.4.3

Comment: @Nick Can you try it on a fresh R session.  May be loading other packages mask the function?

Comment: Refreshed it and still gives me: Error in lazyeval::as.lazy_dots(dots) : could not find function "matches"

Comment: @Nick Not sure why you are getting errors as it works for me. If it is not working, numeric indexing should work `df %>% mutate_each(funs(.-mean(.)), 2:3)`